# how to reformulate general markov property in discrete case

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I read the wiki article on the markov property http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Definition and wondered how to work out this reformulation. It seems intuitively but I can not work it out.

I guess one would need to show two implications to verify the equivalence of both conditions, the general and the special case one:

---

From the general Markov property one simply obtains
$$P(X_n=x_n | X_{n-1},...,X_0 ) = P(X_n=x_n | X_{n-1})$$

But how to continue from there?

---

From the special discrete case Markov property I do not even know any way to start rigorously..

Comment: The added paragraph "And therefore we have" is not correct mathematically. Unrelated: to modify the question after an answer got posted is not recommended.

Comment: Sorry, cleaned up the question and removed (hopefully all) wrong stuff..

Answer (score 0):

For every $n\geqslant0$, $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $P(X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{n}=x_{n} )\ne0$, and every $x$,
$$
P(X_{n+1}=x | X_0=x_0,X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{n}=x_{n} ) = P(X_{n+1}=x | X_{n}=x_{n}).
$$

Comment: Thanks. It seems this is just the given reformulation for the discrete case. I tried to reproduce the reformalation to verify the equivalence..

Comment: The reformulation you added to your post after I posted this answer is incorrect mathematically. After these modifications, the actual content of your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Hm, then even my approach is wrong. How to see that these two conditions are equivalent in the discrete case?

Comment: Question modified *again*. New formulation wrong *again*.